# Node_Modules inside Github

Tags: git, npm, webpack, teamcity, node-modules

Is it possible to put the Node_Modules (seperated from the Project) on to Git? 
And how can i tell my VueJS Project to download every Module inside this Repository.

I already tried with npm ci and this worked. But the Problem is our IT Guys dont want to use this command because it's always downloading these Modules. They want it inside our network the be happen. That why my solution was (maybe) to upload the complete node_modules Folder on our git.

We use Teamcity to build the project for our Preproduction or Live Servers.

I hope you guys can understand me what i'm trying to ask :)

Kind Regards,
Thomas

Comment: If they care about the bandwidth used, they could set up a specific proxy/cache for this. If they care about malicious modules coming in, npm also offers to host the repository on the premises, so only "validated" modules get through. I think any solution is better then putting `node_modules` into a separate repo.

Comment: @Sirko is right. Tell your IT guys that they asking you to do a wrong thing (if you commit `node_modules`, that will be a pain to merge conflicts and your repository size will explode) and that **they** must provide you a proxy solution.

Comment: Philippe is right. They have to provide you a solution, not you. You know what are the good practices and what not to do.

Comment: Ok Thank you guys. I gave these Answers to my IT Guys and my Boss. They will review these Answers and make then a decision. But i think your answers are the only solution right now for us. Thanks and have all of you a nice day.